# Cannot see Example Wallpapers in emulator

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

i wanted to make android live wallpaper app. but there is cubewallpaper app in emulator already installed. so before i wanted to start creating my own i wanted to view that app as i already have to code avaiable form samples. but i cannot see that app in my menu in the emulator. if i go to settings->applicaions->manage application i can see that app there and i can also delete it.

so i deleted it and installed it again from eclipse successfully but still cannot see the app

can some one tell me what id did wrong and where to find that app.

thankx in advance

Comment: Sorry guys i solved it myself just have to press on the homescreen for few second and a popup appears through which i can select and view livewallpapers.

Comment: Also you can press the menu button on the homescreen and select wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

Long press on the Home screen > select wallpapers > live wallpapers. Here you go :)